# How do I change keyboard button "Go" functionality

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, keyboard-events

My app begin with a users login.

when the user push the "Enter" button (after he mark himself on the gridview that gets data from sqlite). The app open alertdialog by inflater.

```
    if (gridView.isClickable()){

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Waiter selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.password_dialog, null);

        AlertDialog.Builder passwordDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
```

The XML file(layout) is only with an editext, on this editext the user needs to fill in

his own password:

> 

```
 passwordDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.get_id_uniq));
        passwordDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.enter_id));


 passwordDialog.setView(dialogLayout);

        passwordDialog.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.next),
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                password = input.getText().toString();
```

and now the problem, when the user click on the editext the keyboard open and
then he puts his password, when he finish and press on the "Go" button on 
the keyboard,the keyboard close but that not enough cause now he need to push again on the alertdialog button and only then the app will check if the password is correct and will move him to the next activity.

i tried to use -
 `android:imeOptions="actionNext"`

and also the "Done", "Go" & "Send" , none of them help.

how do i prevent the double click on 2 different buttons and send the data from the keyboard button and skip the need to push the dialog button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

1. change **dialog** type to AlertDialog, instead of AlertDialog.Builder - that will allow you to dismiss (close) your dialog.
2. use **setOnEditorActionListener** for you input, instead of setPositiveButton
3. Call **dialog.dismiss()**; When user click done on keyboard.

It should look something like that:

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();//note dialog's type
    dialog.setTitle("Let's check it");
    EditText input = new EditText(this);
    dialog.setView(input);//assume this is your input
    input.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
                //What to do when user clicked Done button
                Log.i("user's password:", v.getText().toString());//v.getText().toString(); is what's user has entered
                dialog.dismiss();//close Alert Dialog
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```